# R group and summarize census data

Tags: r

I have census data that is listed by country and separated by wards. There is also a variable for continent. Here is a sample dataset.

```
df1 <- data.frame(country = c("Brazil", "Colombia", "Croatia", "France"), ward_1 = c(45, 35, 15, 80), ward_2 = c(25, 55, 10, 145), ward_23 = c(105, 65, 25, 85), continent = c("Americas", "Americas", "Europe", "Europe"))
```

I need to sum by continent for each of the wards. This is the output I am trying to achieve:

```
df2 <- data.frame(continent = c("Americas", "Europe"), ward_1 = c(80, 95), ward_2 = c(80, 155), ward_23 = c(170, 110))
```

I think I have to use `group_by(continent)` but then how do you output the sum for each ward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `summarise()` after `group_by()`.

In `across()`, it sums up everything in columns with the name that `starts_with` "ward".

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(continent) %>% 
  summarize(across(starts_with("ward"), ~sum(.)))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  continent ward_1 ward_2 ward_23
  <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Americas      80     80     170
2 Europe        95    155     110
```